# Datastore saving value types other than Strings

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore set on my android's backend, and when I try to use the instructions:

```
Entity tour = new Entity("tour", tourKey);
    tour.setProperty("date", "<b>Date:</b><br> Venerdì 07 maggio 2015, ore 20:30 <br> Giovedì 21 maggio 2015, ore 20:30\"");
    tour.setProperty("durata", "<b>Durata:</b><br>Circa 1 ora e ½");;
    Object order = new Integer(1);
    tour.setProperty("order",order);
```

and then query it with:

```
List<Entity> tourss = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
Query query = new Query("tour").setAncestor(tourKey).addSort("order");

for (Entity t : tourss) {
    String date=t.getProperty("date").toString();
    String durata=t.getProperty("durata").toString();

    Object ordine = t.getProperty("order"); // ???
```

the value `ordine` is always a `String`, why? how do I return an `integer`? 
ps. casting doesn't work

Comment: if you want to get your data in original Format use GSON Library to send data to your Server

Comment: I'm already doing that, I need to store different value types into entitites

Comment: In what way does casting "not work"?  Is there a reason why you're declaring an `Object` reference for this property?

Comment: no reason... I was just trying to extract my integer. It doesn't work cause I ain't able to extract my integer